# How to get iOS version of a device from command line?

Tags: ios, appium, instruments

I was trying to find a way to get **iOS** version of a device from command line, like **adb devices** in **Android**, but I couldn't find any solution. All the answers I found were explaining how to obtain it from application.

Is there any way to get iOS version of a device/devices from command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found that **instruments** has `instruments -s devices` command.

When you run the command, it will list all `Known Devices`, but the ones connected will be on top of the list with their **Serial Number.**

A similar output is that:

```
admin$ instruments -s devices
Known Devices:
test iPhone (v7.1.1) (deviceserialnumber)
test iPhone 5S (v7.1.1) (deviceserialnumber)
iPhone - Simulator - iOS 7.1
iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1
iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1
```

I used **sed** command to get only **Serial Number** and **iOS Version:**

```
instruments -s devices | sed -n -E -e 's/.*v(.*)\) \((.*)\)/\2 \1/p'
```

And the output will be:

```
deviceserialnumber 7.1.1
deviceserialnumber 7.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `sw_vers` at the command prompt after you have ssh'ed into the iDevice

```
iPhone:~ root# sw_vers
ProductName:    iPhone OS
ProductVersion: 9.0.2
BuildVersion:   13A452
```

Comment: sw_vers shows the version info of mac, not the connected iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Instruments is now deprecated and now the recommended way is to use `xctrace`. To the get list of available devices on your system you can run:

`xcrun xctrace list devices`

*To get more options on xctrace, run: `man xctrace`*